# Complex number type and functions Open CL C through C# Wrapper

Tags: c#, c, wpf, opencl, fractals

I am making an application in WPF C# that generates fractals. I am using this code that someone made to create a OpenCL kernel and run it in C#:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116907/How-to-Use-Your-GPU-in-NET (It appears to employ another library called Cloo for actually making the OpenCL stuff).

In the kernel I need to be able to use complex numbers to generate my fractals. I have looked around and there is a default c library you can include by putting the line `#include <complex.h>` at the top of the string which contains all the functions I need. (I need more than just the basic adding and multiplying which I can code myself, such as exponential and trig functions, which I really don't want to make by hand).

However when I write this line it cannot compile as "complex.h" cannot be found. So I need some way to point the kernel straight to this file. Another fix might be to just shove the entire library into the kernel which is fine by me, but I have no clue what I need to find and copy to make this work as I know little about c and header files etc.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dotnet use System.Numerics for Complex numbers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex?view=net-6.0

Comment: I used that back when I was executing the code in C# but now I have a OpenCL C file which is compiled at runtime. I pass an array which is then populated by running this C file, the actual computation happens in C, so I need a complex type there.

Comment: You can ask on CodeProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include C libraries in OpenCL C. But OpenCL C is essentially just C99, so you can make your own `complex` type as a `struct`:

```c
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) struct_complex {
    float real;
    float imaginary;
} complex;

complex add(const complex x, const complex y) {
    complex result;
    result.real = x.real+y.real;
    result.imaginary = x.imaginary+y.imaginary;
    return result;
}

...
```

Given that libraries are just code, have a look in the file `complex.h` and copy/adapt what you need. OpenCL C already provides all math functions for foating-point, see [here](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-2-quick-reference-card.pdf). Trigonometric functions / exponent with complex numbers are straightforward then: split the complex number up in the real and imaginary components with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) `exp(i*x) == cos(x)+i*sin(x)` and apply trigonometric identities. [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Functions_of_complex_variables) also might be helpful.